# Split Time Data into Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to split an employees Time Data into multiple Rows base on what time they clock in. For this example if they clock in before 7 am then anything before that will be seperated into a new row of data and everything 7 am and after is the the other row. Here is an example of some data with the desired Result set. This is to help calculate Overtime. If they show up before their set shift then that time is OT pay

```
 Create Table TimeData(
   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [EmployeeID] int NULL,
   [Date] date NULL,
   [TimeIn] time NULL,
   [TimeOut] time Null,
 )

Insert Into TimeData (EmployeeID,Date,Timein,TimeOut)
Values (100,'9/5/2017','06:00','15:00')
```

Result Sets

(100,'9/5/2017','06:00','7:00')

(100,'9/5/2017','07:00','15:00')

The Union All suggestions below pointed me in the right direction and I came up with this query set to create a New Time Record for the employees that punched in before 7:00 am and then update the original.

```
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Timedata( EmployeeID,Date,TimeIn,TimeOut)
 SELECT
  [EmployeeID],
  [Date],
  [TimeIn] AS [Time], '7:00'
 FROM
  TimeData
 WHERE
  [TimeIn] < '07:00:00'
END

BEGIN
 UPDATE TimeData Set TimeIn = '07:00' WHERE TimeIN < '07:00' AND TimeOut <> '7:00'
END
```

Comment: But why? What's the business reason behind this?  Are these shifts? Not my DV BTW.

Comment: The DV is for showing absolutely no research effort.

Comment: This is to help calculate Overtime. If they show up before their set shift then that time is OT pay. The actual stored procedure is much more complex. There will be multiple time entries for one day and total hrs will be calculated but I just needed some collective brain storming on how to clear this hurtle. I don't think it deserves a DV but if it gets DV'd and I still receive help from the community it is still very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use a UNION query:

```
 SELECT EmployeeID, Date, TimeIn, '07:00' as TimeOut FROM timedata WHERE Timein < '07:00'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT EmployeeID, Date, '07:00', TimeOut FROM timedata WHERE TimeOut > '07:00';
```

First selecting all rows where the timein is less than 7am, and setting the appropriate TimeOut. Then selecting all records where TimeOut is over 7am and setting the appropriate TimeIn.

Comment: But what if there is a shift that occurs entirely before or after 7?

Comment: What if they work a shift that starts before midnight? There's a ton of what if's for OP to solve for here. I think UNION ALL is the big Aha! for OP.

Comment: yes it is thank you. I will give start playing with this idea and post my final results.

Answer (score 1):

One quick method via a Cross Apply

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.EmployeeID
      ,A.Date
      ,B.*
 From  TimeData A
 Cross Apply  (values (TimeIn,case when TimeIn<'07:00' then cast('07:00' as time) else TimeOut end)
                     ,(case when TimeIn<'07:00' then cast('07:00' as time) else null end
                      ,case when TimeIn<'07:00' then TimeOut else null end) 
               ) B(TimeIn,TimeOut)
 Where B.TimeIn <> B.TimeOut
```

**Returns  -- Added a 7-3 record**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

USE `UNION ALL` and write a top query that gets the before 7 part, and a bottom query that gets the after 7 part.

Then simply ORDER BY `EmployeeID, TimeIn`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question, is something similar to this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT
    TimeData.EmployeeID,
    [Date],
    TimeData.[TimeIn] AS [Time]
FROM
    TimeData
WHERE
    [TimeIn] < '07:00:00'
UNION
SELECT
    TimeData.EmployeeID,
    [Date],
    TimeData.TimeOut As [Time]
FROM
    TimeData
ORDER BY 
    EmployeeID,
    [Date],
    [Time]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use table driven method for the decision of employee time split.

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeID,
    Date,
    TimeIn = CASE WHEN TD.TimeIn > splitBegin THEN TimeIn ELSE splitBegin END,
    TimeOut = CASE WHEN TD.TimeOut < splitEnd THEN TimeOut ELSE splitEnd END 
from TimeData TD
INNER JOIN (VALUES('00:00','07:00'),('07:00','23:59')) T(splitBegin,splitEnd) 
    ON (TD.TimeIN > T.splitBegin AND TD.TimeIN < T.splitEnd) 
    OR (TD.TimeOut > T.splitBegin AND TD.TimeOut < T.splitEnd)
```